# Count black spots and get their coords with P5.js

Tags: image-processing, p5.js

I would like to count the number of black spots with a minimum size with p5.js but don't know where to start.

[image: This is the type of image I would like to analyse]

I used the Pixels array and checked for RGB values under a certain threshold. The problem is that I also detected spots of 1 pixel. I would like to detect only spots with a minimum width and height.

Here is what I tried :

```
let coords = ()=> {
    let threshold = 20 //Maxium RGB value to detect black spot
    let d = pixelDensity(1)
    let sumX = 0 ,sumY = 0
    let cpt = 0
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            let index = 4 * ((y * d) * width * d + (x * d));
            if (pixels[index] <= threshold && pixels[index + 1] <= threshold && pixels[index + 2] <= threshold) { //If R,G and B are < to threshold
                cpt++; //Number of pixels that are detected
                sumX+=x; //Sum of the Xcoords
                sumY+=y;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(sumX/cpt,sumY/cpt) //Console.log(average Xcoord , average Ycoord) only works if there is only one spot
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the work you have done?

Comment: Yes, sorry
I edited it

Comment: perhaps a library... https://www.tetoki.eu/vida/.

Comment: There's a problem: What if two dots are right next to eachother. Also, is there a set size for the dots? You could work with that pixel by pixel size instead of check each pixel. Say the size of each dot is 5 pixels, you can check every for 5 pixels in each direction, that would work. But you do need to know the size. Otherwise, I agree with v.k you need a library.